# The packages i installed in one google colab notebook do not show up in a new one

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, install.packages

I installed **tensorflow 2** in this notebook [notebook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La8Kt.png).

But when i opened a new notebook, I had the previous version [notebook2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpoFU.png).

I am new to using google colab and don't know if this is how colab works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use packages installed in one instance of google Colab, in another instance.

Every-time you create a new notebook it creates a new instance. So, it's like you opened a file in another computer. But you want to access the files from previous computer. So It's not possible.

You can check the instances by clicking on RunTime -> Manage Sessions.

Comment: In google Colab terminology "instance" is called "session".

Comment: Thank you, But is there a work around to overcome this ?

Comment: Add this line before importing tensorflow:`%tensorflow_version 2.x`
This makes the tensorflow to use version 2.x.